# Webcam not detected on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 with Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th gen

Tags: lenovo, webcam

Although I've been using this Lenovo X1 Carbon with Ubuntu 18.04 for multiple months without issue, last week, it stopped being able to detect the webcam. None of the applications that use webcam functioned (Cheese, Zoom, Google Hangouts.)

I rebooted the computer, uninstalled and reinstalled various cam apps, nothing has worked yet.

I also tried a bootable USB with Ubuntu 20.04 - same result.

`sudo lshw` detected no webcam also.

How can I troubleshoot the webcam and get it functioning again?

Answer (score 0):

Following [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/dapi5q/camera_on_x1_carbon_7th_gen_not_working/), I entered BIOS at startup by pressing `Enter` at the splash Lenovo screen.  I did not find a specific config for the webcam, so instead I reset all the start up configs to factory settings.  (By pressing `F6` or `F9` or similar within the bios settings - it was an option at the bottom of the screen.)

I restarted my laptop and the camera was back!

If that doesn't work, re-installing webcam drivers from the Lenovo website is another option.

Hope this helps other people.